# TIdUPDServer listening on IPv6 not working

Tags: delphi, udp, indy

Am I correct that the following code will enable a TIdUDPServer to listen on all IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces?

```
with UDPServer.Bindings.Add do
begin
  IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  IP := '';
  Port := FPort;
end;
with UDPServer.Bindings.Add do
begin
  IPVersion := Id_IPv6;
  IP := '';
  Port := FPort;
end;
UDPServer.Active := True;
```

It works with IPv4 but I don't receive anything when sending via TIdUPDClient with IPv6 to ::1. Showing the sending code is not so easy.  This is the only part that differs based on IP version.

```
IPv6 := copy(IP,1,1)='[';
if IPv6 then IP := copy(IP,2,Length(IP)-2);
UDP := TIdUDPClient.Create;
if IPv6 then UDP.IPVersion := Id_IPv6
else UDP.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
UDP.Host := IP;
UDP.Port := Port;
UDP.BroadcastEnabled := copy(IP,Length(IP)-3,4)= '.255';
UDP.Connect;
```

The code sending the data simply uses

```
UDP.SendBuffer(Buf);
```

I'm testing sending on the same PC as receiving.
Receiving works when sending to 127.0.0.1 but not [::1].  There is no error during the .Connect and .SendBuffer commands so appears to be sent but nothing is received in the UDP Server.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Please be more specific. Which platform(s) are you targeting? Not all platforms allow you to bind separate interfaces to the same port even if they are using different IP versions. Internally, if you don't setup any `Bindings` at all, `TIdUDPServer` will create separate IPv4 and IPv6 bindings for you on its `DefaultPort` for all platforms except Linux and Android.

Comment: Ideally, the best solution is to create 1 binding using a dual-stack socket, but Indy does not natively support that feature yet. But what you could do is create a single IPv6 binding, and then use the `OnBeforeBind` event to manually disable the `IPV6_V6ONLY` option on that binding to allow IPv4 traffic on it.

Comment: Platform is Windows. I wasn't creating any bindings initially but sending via IPv6 wasn't working so tried the above code. I assumed the IPVersion property was used to create 1 binding to whichever was selected.  What is the purpose of this property otherwise?

Comment: The way you are setting up the bindings is correct. Please show the rest of your code they is not working as you are expecting, and explain why it is not working the way you want. Also, show your client code, too.

Comment: I added client code above.  I've implemented OnBeforeBind and SetSockOpt with IPV6_V6ONLY set to 0, and it again works with IPv4 and not IPv6.  Is there perhaps some issue sending and receiving via IPv6 on the same PC?

Comment: Did you verify with a packet sniffer like Wireshark that IPv6 traffic is being sent out from the client and is reaching the server's IPv6 port? https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback